# How to authenticate to Google Gemini Pro Vision AI, using Python SDK, and in-line credentials?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to use Google's Vertex Python SDK, but I don't want to lug a `credentials.json` file around. I'd rather store the secret parts of the file in a Key Vault and insert at runtime. But I can't find a simple way to use an in-line dict to define the credential.

The `from_service_account_file` wants a file path.

**Example script**:

```
import io
import json
import logging

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

# ----------------------------------------------------------------

AZURE_KEYVAULT_URL = 'https://my-kv-name.vault.azure.net/'

GCP_PROJECT_ID = 'my-proj'
GCP_REGION = 'my-region'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------

def get_secrets_from_key_vault(key_vault_url, secret_names):   
    az_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()  
    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=key_vault_url, credential=az_credential)   
    secrets = {}  
    for secret_name in secret_names:  
        secret = secret_client.get_secret(secret_name)  
        secrets[secret_name] = secret.value  
  
    return secrets 

# -----------------------------------------------------------------

secret_names = [
    'secret1', 
    'secret2'
  ]

secret_values = get_secrets_from_key_vault(AZURE_KEYVAULT_URL, secret_names)

gcp_credentials = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "vertexai-poc-400414",
  "private_key_id": secret_values['secret1'],
  "private_key": secret_values['secret2'],
  "client_email": "me@cool.com",
  "client_id": "long-number-here",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/me@cool.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}

# The `from_service_account_file` wants a file path, not a dict. I can't find an alternative method.

gcp_credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(  # <---problem is here. 
    gcp_credentials_string,
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

# Handle auth refresh
if gcp_credentials.expired:
    gcp_credentials.refresh(Request())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use base64 to encode the service account JSON key file contents. Store that as a string in vault. Do the reverse when you read the secret.

Replace `Credentials.from_service_account_file` with `Credentials.from_service_account_info` and use `json.loads()` to convert the base64 decoded string into a dictionary that `from_service_account_info` can use.

Refer to the documentation for more information:

[google.oauth2.service_account module](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html)

For future improvement, you do not need to use a service account file or secret on Azure. You can use Workload Identity Federation instead.

[Configure workload identity federation with AWS or Azure](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-other-clouds)